# How to fix up compilation errors in auto-generated EF migrations when an entity is moved to a different namespace

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

The existing EF migrations reference entities in `Foo.Entities`. I moved these to `Bar.Entities`. However the existing `*.Designer.cs` files still have references to `Foo.Entities` and cause the build to fail.

`Foo` and `Bar` are different projects, with the migrations residing in `Foo` in my case.

I could of course fix these up manually (or by regexing), but this feels wrong as these files are auto-generated.

Maybe I'm missing something. What's the proper way to tackle such a namespace change?

I'm using:
Asp.Net Core 2.0.2
EF Core 2.0.2

Comment: The `*.Designer.cs` files read `// <auto-generated />` at the top. Should they instead be saying `// <auto-scaffolded />`, if I am in fact allowed to edit them manually?